# android RecyclerView setOnScrollChangeListener need api 23?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am using volley - CardView and RecyclerView to create a project
this project give information from the json url and show in my application

But the RecyclerView.setOnScrollChangeListener just need api 23 and that will not run in other versions

What should I do?

My dependencies:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
compile files('libs/volley.jar') }
```

Comment: are using Recycler view from support library ?

Comment: RecyclerView uses `addOnScrollListener(RecyclerView.OnScrollListener)` which works on all API levels.

Comment: recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(recyclerView.OnScrollListener);
is this right?

Answer (score 13):

You can use `addOnScrollListener` it works perfectly fine

```
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);

            //onScrollStateChanged will be fire every time you scroll
            //Perform your operation here

            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Be aware that the callback of `RecyclerView#setOnScrollChangeListener` is triggered all the time while scrolling and `RecyclerView.OnScrollListener#onScrollStateChanged` only when a change happens. Depending on what you want to do you may have to override `RecyclerView.OnScrollListener#onScrolled` as well.